# Is Foo<?> equivalent to the unparamaterised Foo?

Tags: java, generics

I have two classes, Foo and Bar, with type declarations:

```
class Foo<T>
class Bar<Foo>
```

This causes a compiler warning, as the Foo argument in Bar is not paramaterised. Ideally I would like to avoid the compiler warning, but I do want Bar to accept any Foo. So I tried this:

```
class Foo<T>
class Bar<Foo<?>>
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm worried there might be a subtle difference I'm missing. Is there?

Comment: Declaring a class as `Bar<Foo<?>>` would be a syntax error - maybe you mean declaring a *variable* as `Bar<Foo<?>>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. Consider this -

```
List<?> myList;
```

You cannot put anything into this list except null. You also cannot get anything out of this list except an `Object`. So compiler won't allow you to corrupt this list's type invariant by letting you add objects of different types. If you try to do so, you will get a compile time error.

But if you consider the following list (a *raw type*) -

```
List myList;
```

then you are allowed to put anything/get anything from here. So one can easily corrupt this list by putting objects of different types, and you'll only find out about this from the `ClassCastException` at run time (if you are lucky....).

So, for your case, use the following approach -

```
class Foo<T>
class Bar<Foo<?>>
```

and stay away from the first one if you can.

For more information, check out [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) -

1. Item 23 - *Don't use raw types in new code*
2. Item 26 - *Favor generic types*

Comment: Ah, of course. Unfortunately I think I'm asking the wrong question. May have to ask a quite similar one soon :p

Answer (score 1):

`Foo<?>` is semantically the same as `Foo<? extends Object>`: it is a `Foo` with type parameter of something specific, but the only thing known about "something" is that it is some subclass of Object (which isn't saying too much, since all classes are subclasses of Object).